# How to solve "Account_user" not found in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I recently joined with an ongoing project which has done using the Django framework. 
When I run the following command it didn't create any migration file.

`py manage.py makemigrations --settings=hopster.settings.local`

When I run the following command as described in the readme file in the project.

`py manage.py migrate --settings=hopster.settings.local`

I receive the following error 
"django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "Account_user" does not exist"

It has local.py, dev.py, prod.py files base.py files instead of settings.py file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3qPK.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rywbP.png)

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Show the *full* error traceback, as *text*, in the question.

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback for your error?  It looks like somewhere in your code, `Account_user` is being import/referenced when it isn't defined.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `python manage.py` first use `python manage.py makemigrations account`
and then use `python manage.py migrate`

before

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a custom user model. First of all, you need to check your settings.

Take a look at this link to find out more information about customizing user model -  [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

if
`py manage.py makemigrations --settings=hopster.settings.local` does not create any migration try to run `py manage.py makemigrations [account] --settings=hopster.settings.local`, where [account] is the name of the app in `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting